# Prometheus alarm - request by percentage and not by absolute

Tags: regex, monitoring, prometheus

I am trying to write a query for Prometheus monitoring system that will count the total number of nodes that are up that ends with the name presto.worker and then it will calculate how many of those are no available and will trigger an alarm if there is more then 10% are not healthy.

I have written something but it doesn't work and need a little bit tuning below my query:

```
count by(presto_failuredetector_HeartbeatFailureDetector_ActiveCount) (up{instance=~"[A-Za-z.]+[A-Za-z.-]+(presto.)+(worker)"}) < 0.9
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn’t do percentage part

Comment: That is my detector - presto_failuredetector_HeartbeatFailureDetector_ActiveCount and
This is how to match my workers -  (up{instance=~"[A-Za-z.]+[A-Za-z.-]+(presto.)+(worker)"})

Answer (score 0):

This can give you what you want:

```
sum(up{instance=~"[A-Za-z.]+[A-Za-z.-]+(presto.)+(worker)"})
/
count(up{instance=~"[A-Za-z.]+[A-Za-z.-]+(presto.)+(worker)"})
> 0.9
```

This works since `up` exposes 1 for healthy and 0 for unhealthy targets. So `sum(up)` is the same as `count(up == 1)`.

Comment: It triggers the alarm when my two of my nodes are up and available

Comment: I have notice when I do a query count(up{instance=~"[A-Za-z.]+[A-Za-z.-]+(presto.)+(worker)"}) .
The result I am getting is 1 and I have two nodes in autoscaling groups so I should get the number two but it doesn't happens.